# ng-click not working on button click inside kendo grid header template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid which is rendered dynamically based on the table selected by the user. The grid has a last column which has a header template in which I have provided a button. On click of this button I want to call angularjs controller function which I did using `ng-click=ctrl.addnewRow()` .

Problem I am facing is that, when the grid is loaded for the table in the first Kendo TAB the "+"(add) button does not work. When I navigate to a different tab which is using the same grid and same template, the button click works as expected. I have been scratching my head to figure out what the problem is, but could not find the problem or solution. Here is a snapshot of the page. I have used highlighting for sensitive data.

[image]

See the "+" button, and the code below in the debug window. Thats not working for the first tab.

Let me know if anyone needs some more information.

**EDIT**

I have created a [kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ohICE/13) where the add buttons do not work for both tables. I did not add any tabs based on my scenario, but this fiddle should help

Comment: are you 100% sure that the button is not hidden behind transparent elements? Easy way to check is to select the magnifier top-left in dev tools and hover over the button.

Comment: Yes I have checked that. The button is rendered from a kendo-template and there is absolutely nothing on top of it.

Comment: Did you try to call a local function with the ng-click?

Comment: I added a `test()` function which just shows an alert and now it does not work for any buttons. `ng-click="test()"`

Comment: Can you try and set up a jsfiddler with some dummy data?

Comment: Please share your header template script.

Comment: Am of work right now will post a fiddle tomorrow

Comment: Header template is pretty simple' <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ctrl.addnewRow()"><i class="fa fa-plus"/></button>'

Comment: The first thing I would check is that you aren't accidentally in a nested $scope. Consider installing an Angular dev tool such as Batarang to help monitor your scope vars. 

As a blind guess before seeing your jsfiddler - try doing `ng-click=$parent.test()`

Comment: Hey guys, I have added a kendo Ui dojo link. Really appreciate if someone could have a look.